# Firebase security rules fails during multi path update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In firebase I set security rules in order to secure some nodes.

**Problem**

When I use multi path update to update multiple paths at the same time, If one security rule fails for any of the multiple paths, then the whole update fails.

**example of my problem**

Lets say I have 3 nodes (users, people , tasks) in my real time database, in android the way to update the 3 paths together is by doing something like this:

```
     Map multi-update =new HashMap();

    multi-update.put("users/user1/name","any_name");
    multi-update.put("people/user2/status", "any_status");
    multi-update.put("tasks/task1/details", "any_details");

    DatabaseReference root=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    //update
     root.updateChildren(multi-update);
```

lets say my rules are like this:

```
    "users":{
       ".write":"true"
     }

    ,"people":{
        ".write":"true"
      }
    ,"tasks":{
        ".write":"false"
        }
```

since task doesn't allow writes to it, then the multi path update is never updating until all paths allow the write.

can someone explain why that happens?

Thanks.

Comment: This behavior is by design: a multi-location update is only committed if all of the changes succeed. If you want the writes to be committed individually, use a separate call to `updateChildren` for each of them.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if I call update to each 3 nodes individually is it still a multipath update?

Comment: No it isn't, but that's just a matter of definition. You don't want a multi-path update, because you want each update to succeed individually. This sounds very much like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) at this point: what are you trying to accomplish by performing these three updates?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I want the writes to go to the database without having to depend on each other (I don't want to chain them together, beacuse onComplete call back is not persisted when connection is lost). I want to always make sure they will go together when I send them (online or offline).

Comment: The added advantage of sending as a single packet, if you don't want the atomic writes is honestly negligible. But regardless: you will need to do separate calls, since there's no way to use a single multi-location update in the way you want.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so you are saying (I don't really need to use multipath update)? If yes then why did you at firebase think of adding this functionality? what is the purpose?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If I am able to update A then B then C , then what is the purpose of updating A,B and C together?

Comment: The purpose is to update multiple location in a single operation, which either succeeds (passing all security rules) or fails as one.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen also updating A then B then C after each other will do the same thing? either passes or fails also.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen anyway I appreciate your reply. Just had a doubt if not using it will do any difference.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields):

> Simultaneous updates made this way are atomic: either all updates
>   succeed or all updates fail.

So the problem you are describing isn't actually a problem but the intended behaviour of `root.updateChildren(multi-update);`

If this behaviour is a problem in your case you could change your firebase rules to give permission to all parts of your multi-update or split up your multi-update in parts to make sure that the parts that can succeed will succeed.

Another option in your case would be to check for errors like this:

```
root.updateChildren(multi-update, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError firebaseError, DatabaseReference firebase) {
        if (firebaseError != null)
        {
            //Update the minimum required fields
        }
    }
});
```

The downside here is you don't know what part of your update failed.

Comment: But sometimes one or more rule will need to fail due to some restrictions, and some nodes should be kept together with single update. What should we do in this case?

Comment: Lets say B writes to A and B nodes simultaneously by atomic write, then lets say some day A decides to block or unfriends B. Then when B will do the atomic write and it won't update in A node neither in B node due to security rules. Then what should we do?

Comment: @svi.data I added another option to my answer, maybe thats what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to avoid putting code in call backs, but thanks for your help anyway.